# Input field validation in angular using formControl

Tags: angular, validation, input

I want to tag an error message when the user touches on that particular field and and then clicks outside without entering anything. I am not sure why the below code doesnt work .
Guys Any inputs..I need some serious suggestions pls.

```
<form [formGroup]="personalInfoForm" novalidate [ngClass]="{submitted: formSumitAttempt}"> 
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <label for="firstName" class="userID control-label">First Name</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Name" formControlName="firstName"  [(ngModel)]="firstName"  required>
                <div *ngIf ="firstName?.touched && firstName?.errors" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <div [hidden]="!firstName.errors.required">
                        Name is required
                    </div>
                    </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Something to read: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation. I don't think you can use `formControlName` and `ngModel` at the same time.

Comment: Although now I have removed the ngModel from my code , the error message is still not getting tagged.  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Name" formControlName="firstName"  required>

Comment: Alternatively, if I use the below code , I am getting error , "TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined" 

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Name" formControlName="firstName"  required>
            <div *ngIf="firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">
                    Name is required.
                  </div>
                </div>

Comment: remove formControlName, use `<input id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="firstName" required>`

Then, use the one with firstName.dirty

Comment: @JoshuaChanERROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:

      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

      Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

Answer (score 0):

in your component

```
personalInfoForm=new formGroup({
 firstname:new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
})
```

your HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="personalInfoForm" novalidate [ngClass]="{submitted: formSumitAttempt}"> 
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <label for="firstName" class="userID control-label">First Name</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Name" formControlName="firstName"   required>
                <div *ngIf ="personalInfoForm.controls['firstname'].hasError('required')" class="alert alert-danger">
 Name is required </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

Comment: check now there was a typo i rectified it

Comment: Actually the below code worked. Not sure , why the code you gave thrown error  :( .. I tried to slightly modify from the code that you gave and it worked 

 <div *ngIf="personalInfoForm.controls['firstName'].errors?.required &&
                personalInfoForm.controls['firstName'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">

Comment: @RajeshAny idea how to tag an error message to that particular field when I click on submit button and if the firstName field doesnt have any value entered.